# ADFS chained over 2 forests for Single Sign On on Office 365

Tags: exchange-2010, single-sign-on, adfs, microsoft-office-365

Is it possible to provide SSO to Office 365 in following Scenario?

- Windows 2008 Forests
- Exchange 2010
- Hybrid Infrastructure with On Premise and Cloud Users

Account Domain ->
Account Domain ->  Resource Domain with Exchange 2010 -> Office 365
Account Domain ->

Users login to Account Domains.
Forest Trust is established between Account and Resource Domain.
The Resource Domain should be connected through ADFS 2.0

Best regards
Mischa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see http://community.office365.com/en-us/w/sso/295.aspx for details. Basically dirsync is the issue here. This is currently not a supported configuration although this may change in the future.